# 4-Bit ALU to BCD display

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, bcd, alu

I have a mega-assignment and the last part(for extra marks) is to display the output of a designed ALU using two 7-seg displays. These should display the result of the operations performed in the ALU. I am performing logical and arithmetic operations and I can only use the lower display for logical operations. For the arithmetic operations I need to use BCD code to display the answers. **My ALU is working fine**, I am finding it hard to do the decoder part. I don't even know if I am on the right track. Help!

### CODE

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_unsigned.ALL;


entity codeALU is
    Port (  A : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           B : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           Cin : in  STD_LOGIC;
          S0 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           S1 : in  STD_LOGIC;
              M : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Cout : out  STD_LOGIC;
              Z : out STD_LOGIC;
           F : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
              bcd1 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0);
              bcd2 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0));
end codeALU;

architecture Behavioral of codeALU is
begin

process(A, B, M, Cin, S1, S0)

    variable temp : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
    variable Fx : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
    variable Cx, Zx : STD_LOGIC;
    variable Sel : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0);

begin
    Sel := S1 & S0 & Cin;
        Cx := '0';
        Zx := '0';
    if M = '0' then
        Z <= '0';
        case Sel(2 downto 1) is
            when "00" => 
                Fx :=  A AND B;
                Zx := '0';
            when "01" =>
                Fx :=  A XOR B;
            when "10" =>
                Fx :=  A OR B;
            when "11" => 
                Fx :=  A XNOR B;
            when others =>
                null;
        end case;

            case Fx is
            when "0000"=> bcd1 <="0000001";  -- '0'
            when "0001"=> bcd1 <="1001111";  -- '1'
            when "0010"=> bcd1 <="0010010";  -- '2'
            when "0011"=> bcd1 <="0000110";  -- '3'
            when "0100"=> bcd1 <="1001100";  -- '4'
            when "0101"=> bcd1 <="0100100";  -- '5'
            when "0110"=> bcd1 <="0100000";  -- '6'
            when "0111"=> bcd1 <="0001111";  -- '7'
            when "1000"=> bcd1 <="0000000";  -- '8'
            when "1001"=> bcd1 <="0000100";  -- '9'
            when others=> bcd1 <="1111111";
            end case;

    else
        case Sel is
            when "000" =>
                temp := (B(3)&B(3 downto 1) + ('0'&A));
                Fx := temp(3 downto 0);
                Cx := temp(4);
            when "001" =>
                temp := (A(3)&A(3 downto 1) + ('0'&B));
                Fx := temp(3 downto 0);
                Cx := temp(4);
            when "010" =>
                temp := ('0'&A) + ('0'&B);
                Fx := temp(3 downto 0);
                Cx := temp(4);
            when "011" =>
                temp := ('0'&A) + ('0'&B) + ('0'&Cin);
                Fx := temp(3 downto 0);
                Cx := temp(4);
            when "100" =>
                temp := ('0'&A) + (not B);
                Fx := temp(3 downto 0);
                Cx := temp(4);
            when "101" =>
                temp := (not B) + ('0'&A) + 1;
                Fx := temp(3 downto 0);
                Cx := temp(4);
            when "110" =>
                temp := ('0'&A) + ('0'&B(3 downto 1));
                Fx := temp(3 downto 0);
                Cx := temp(4);
            when "111" =>
                temp := ('0'&B) + ('0'&A(3 downto 1));
                Fx := temp(3 downto 0);
                Cx := temp(4);
            when others => 
                null;
        end case;

        case Fx is

            when "0000"=> bcd2 <="0000001";  -- '0'
            when "0001"=> bcd2 <="1001111";  -- '1'
            when "0010"=> bcd2 <="0010010";  -- '2'
            when "0011"=> bcd2 <="0000110";  -- '3'
            when "0100"=> bcd2 <="1001100";  -- '4'
            when "0101"=> bcd2 <="0100100";  -- '5'
            when "0110"=> bcd2 <="0100000";  -- '6'
            when "0111"=> bcd2 <="0001111";  -- '7'
            when "1000"=> bcd2 <="0000000";  -- '8'
            when "1001"=> bcd2 <="0000100";  -- '9'
            when others=> bcd2 <="1111111";
            end case;

        for i in 0 to 3 loop
            Zx := Zx or Fx(i);
        end loop;
            Z <= not Zx;
    end if;
        F <= Fx;
        Cout <= Cx;
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

### Test Bench

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY test4ALU IS
END test4ALU;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF test4ALU IS 

    -- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)

    COMPONENT codeALU
    PORT(
         A : IN  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
         B : IN  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
         Cin : IN  std_logic;
         S0 : IN  std_logic;
         S1 : IN  std_logic;
         M : IN  std_logic;
         Cout : OUT  std_logic;
         Z : OUT  std_logic;
         F : OUT  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
         bcd1 : OUT  std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
         bcd2 : OUT  std_logic_vector(6 downto 0)
        );
    END COMPONENT;


   --Inputs
   signal A : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := (others => '0');
   signal B : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := (others => '0');
   signal Cin : std_logic := '0';
   signal S0 : std_logic := '0';
   signal S1 : std_logic := '0';
   signal M : std_logic := '0';

    --Outputs
   signal Cout : std_logic;
   signal Z : std_logic;
   signal F : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := (others => '0');
   signal bcd1 : std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
   signal bcd2 : std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
   -- No clocks detected in port list. Replace <clock> below with 
   -- appropriate port name 


BEGIN

    -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
   uut: codeALU PORT MAP (
          A => A,
          B => B,
          Cin => Cin,
          S0 => S0,
          S1 => S1,
          M => M,
          Cout => Cout,
          Z => Z,
          F => F,
          bcd1 => bcd1,
          bcd2 => bcd2
        );



   -- Stimulus process
   stim_proc: process
   begin        
      -- hold reset state for 100 ns.
      wait for 100 ns;  

        A <= "1001";
        B <= "1111";

        M <= '0';
        wait for 50 ns;
        S1 <= '0';
        S0 <= '0';
        wait for 50 ns;
        S1 <= '0';
        S0 <= '1';
        wait for 50 ns;
        S1 <= '1';
        S0 <= '0';
        wait for 50 ns;
        S1 <= '1';
        S0 <= '1';
        wait for 50 ns;

        M <= '1';
        S1 <= '0';
        S0 <= '0';
        Cin <= '0';
        wait for 50 ns;
        S1 <= '0';
        S0 <= '0';
        Cin <= '1';
        wait for 50 ns;
        S1 <= '0';
        S0 <= '1';
        Cin <= '0';
        wait for 50 ns;
        S1 <= '0';
        S0 <= '1';
        Cin <= '1';
        wait for 50 ns;
        S1 <= '1';
        S0 <= '0';
        Cin <= '0';
        wait for 50 ns;
        S1 <= '1';
        S0 <= '0';
        Cin <= '1';
        wait for 50 ns;
        S1 <= '1';
        S0 <= '1';
        Cin <= '0';
        wait for 50 ns;
        S1 <= '1';
        S0 <= '1';
        Cin <= '1';

      wait;
   end process;

    process
   begin               
     for i in 0 to 9 loop
           F <= conv_std_logic_vector(i,4);
          wait for 50 ns;
     end loop;
   end process;

END;
```

[image: Timing diagram for the ALU with BCD display]

[image: ALU before the BCD]

Comment: For binary to BCD conversion, take a look at [Double dabble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dabble), and [Convert 8bit binary number to BCD in VHDL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23871792/2352082).

Answer (score 0):

You've issue in your test bench:
Within codeALU entity is F defined as out signal. Within you test bench signal F is used to map F out from component codeALU. In the name less process below in test bench the signal F gets value: F <= conv_std_logic_vector(i,4);

It's unusable behavior. You see it in modelsim as red X's (not defined).